# SELECT with 2 x sub queries returns duplicate results - how to fix?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I had this code which combines order details and gives you a product id and variation id for an orders items.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT meta_value as product_id
    FROM ctc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    LEFT JOIN ctc_woocommerce_order_items ON ctc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = ctc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
    WHERE meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND order_id = 3989
) as product_id,
(
    SELECT meta_value as variation_id
    FROM ctc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    LEFT JOIN ctc_woocommerce_order_items ON ctc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = ctc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
    WHERE meta_key = '_variation_id'
    AND order_id = 3989
) as variation_id
```

Results of this are:

```
----------------------------------
| product_id | variation_id      |
----------------------------------
| 3921       | 3922              |
----------------------------------
```

Works fine if there is only 1 item in the order, if there are multiple items (records), if I change the first SELECT to SELECT * FROM the results are:

```
----------------------------------
| product_id | variation_id      |
----------------------------------
| 17420       | 17422            |
| 17420       | 16963            |
| 17420       | 0                |
| 16961       | 17422            |
| 16961       | 16963            |
| 16961       | 0                |
| 33601       | 17422            |
| 33601       | 16963            |
| 33601       | 0                |
----------------------------------
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
----------------------------------
| product_id | variation_id      |
----------------------------------
| 17420       | 17422            |
----------------------------------
| 16961       | 16963            |
----------------------------------
| 33601       | 0                |
----------------------------------
```

I think this is to do with the results from each subquery being combined but can't get to the expected result above. How to do it?

Comment: i think you miss a group by with select *

Comment: A result set without a data set is completely bonkers.

Comment: Go back and look at the answer I suggested for your previous question on this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49942860/5790584

Comment: I attempted the same with that code, but wasn't sure on how to amend that for multiple row results

Comment: Change the join condition from `oi.order_id = 3988` to `oi.order_id IN (<list of order_id>)`. Take the join condition off altogether to get an unfiltered set.

Comment: This question, like your last one, would be easier for people to help you with if you posted more useful details. See this post for tools and examples. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_product_id' THEN meta_value END) as product_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_variation_id' THEN meta_value END) as variation_id
FROM ctc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim LEFT JOIN 
     ctc_woocommerce_order_items oi
     ON oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
WHERE oi.order_id = 3989 AND oim.meta_key IN ('_product_id', '_variation_id')
GROUP BY oim.order_item_id
```

Comment: Kinda works, top rows returned correctly, but has 2 NULL rows at the end